# How to apply function in Pandas containing self

Tags: pandas, function, self

I have the following dataframe (called `df`):

[image]

I want to apply the `chandelier_exit` function which is given by the following code:

```
class Bill_Ackman():
    def avg_true_range(self, df): 
      ind = range(0,len(df))
      indexlist = list(ind)
      df.index = indexlist
    
      for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if index != 0:
          tr1 = row["High"] - row["Low"]
          tr2 = abs(row["High"] - df.iloc[index-1]["Close"])
          tr3 = abs(row["Low"] - df.iloc[index-1]["Close"])
    
          true_range = max(tr1, tr2, tr3)
          df.set_value(index,"True Range", true_range)
    
      df["Avg TR"] = df["True Range"].rolling(min_periods=14, window=14, center=False).mean()
      return df

    
    def chandelier_exit(self, df): # default period is 22
    
      df_tr = self.avg_true_range(df)
    
      rolling_high = df_tr["High"][-1:].max()
      rolling_low = df_tr["Low"][-1:].max()
    
      chandelier_long = rolling_high - df_tr.iloc[-1]["Avg TR"] * 1.85
      chandelier_short = rolling_low - df_tr.iloc[-1]["Avg TR"] * 1.85


Bill_Ackman.chandelier_exit(df)
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: chandelier_exit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'
```

How do I apply that function?

Comment: `ClassName().chandelier_exit(df)` didn't work?

Comment: What's ClassName() ? is it the name of the script? the script containing the function is called createFields.py and it's run in Anaconda Spyder.

Comment: That function is intended to be used as a bound class function (hence the `self`). If it is not a class function then something is wrong with the script that you are taking it from.

Comment: Right... let me add a response so you can view the whole code ... I am still getting an error:
TypeError: chandelier_exit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'

Comment: I have edited the original post with the class added to it

Comment: The class name is Bill_Ackman. Try `Bill_Ackman().chandelier_exit(df)`.